# VBA multiple if else if statement with range and text

Tags: excel, vba

would you anyone pls help me with this. when i run the marcos, i got wrong number of arguments and invalid property

```
If Range(("K2") = "Technical", ("J2") = "Band 23", ("J2") = "Band 24") Then
    Range("U2").Value = "Core Team Trained"
    Else: If Range(("K2") = "Technical", ("J2") = "Band 25", "Band 26", "Band 30") Then Range("U2").Value = "PL Trained"
    Else: If Range(("K2") = "Management", ("J2") = "Band 25", "Band 26", "Band 30", "Band 31", "Band 40") Then Range("U2").Value = "Champion Trained"
    Else: If Range(("K2") = "Project Mgm", ("J2") = "Band 21", "Band 22", "Band 23") Then Range("U2").Value = "CORE TEAM MEMBER TRAINED"
    Else: If Range(("K2") = "Project Mgm", ("J2") = "Band 24") Then Range("U2").Value = "PL TRAINED"
    Else: If Range(("K2") = "Project Mgm", ("J2") = "Band 25") Then Range("U2").Value = "PL CERTIFIED"
    Else: If Range(("K2") = "Project Mgm", ("J2") = "Band 26") Then Range("U2").Value = "SME TRAINED"
    Else: If Range(("K2") = "Project Mgm", ("J2") = "Band 30") Then Range("U2").Value = "SME CERTIFIED"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using commas? `If Range("K2") = "Technical" Or Range("J2") = "Band 23" Or Range("J2") = "Band 24" Then` - And your parentheses are wrong... using this corrected line, fix all of your other lines as well.

Comment: Some, if not all, of these lines are better written in a `Select Case` structure when I look at it in a first glance. Sidenote, make sure to use worksheet references too to avoid the implicit `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Maybe you mean: `If Range("K2") = "Technical" And (Range("J2") = "Band 23" Or Range("J2") = "Band 24") Then` ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started, I would advise using a `Select Case` structure and make sure to at least use a `Worksheet` reference to avoid the implicit `ActiveSheet`. You never know where your code may get accessed from.

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    Select Case .Range("K2").Value
    Case "Technical"
        Select Case CLng(Right(.Range("J2").Value, 2))
        Case 23, 24
            .Range("U2").Value = "Core Team Trained"
        Case 25, 26, 30
            .Range("U2").Value = "PL Trained"
        End Select
    Case "Management"
        Select Case CLng(Right(.Range("J2").Value, 2))
        Case 25, 26, 30, 31, 40
            .Range("U2").Value = "Champion Trained"
        End Select
    Case "Project Mgm"
        Select Case CLng(Right(.Range("J2").Value, 2))
        Case 21 - 23
            .Range("U2").Value = "CORE TEAM MEMBER TRAINED"
        Case 24
            .Range("U2").Value = "PL TRAINED"
        Case 25
            .Range("U2").Value = "PL CERTIFIED"
        Case 26
            .Range("U2").Value = "SME TRAINED"
        Case 30
            .Range("U2").Value = "SME CERTIFIED"
        End Select
    End Select
End With

End Sub
```

Not the shortest of codes, but clarity does come a long way.

Comment: I'll take long easy to read code over short confusing code any day.

Comment: thank you so much for helping! i am very new to VBA!